# Unknown parent error in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I am getting a error that is preventing me to pull, even force pull.

```
hg command error:
transaction abort!
rollback completed
abort: data/assets/images/skins/file/skin.jpg.i@0727c4489edc: unknown parent!
```

Is there anyway to remove, revert or fix just this file, its not even used, and it's preventing any pulling.

**UPDATE**
After Running hg verify

```
checking changesets
checking manifests
crosschecking files in changesets and manifests
checking files
 assets/images/skins/hein/Heineken-skin.jpg@236: 0727c4489edc in manifests not found
 assets/images/skins/vw/VW_10_Revive_Website_Takeover.jpg@153: 877324921450 in manifests not found
 assets/images/skins/vw/VW_10_Revive_Website_Takeover.jpg@171: 45e8aee1c524 in manifests not found
warning: orphan revlog 'data/assets/images/skins/hein/Heineken-skin.jpg.d'
warning: orphan revlog 'data/assets/images/skins/vw/VW_10_Revive_Website_Takeover.jpg.d'
1268 files, 256 changesets, 2101 total revisions
2 warnings encountered!
3 integrity errors encountered!
```

(first damaged changeset appears to be 153)

Seems to be 2 images, How can I fix this?

Comment: If you put store/00changelog.i/d store/00manifest.i/d and the two orphan .d online, I can try to fix them for you.

Otherwise you might be able to create a new repository using hg convert from hg to hg with a filemap excluding this two files: mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RepositoryCorruption

Comment: btw are those two files the only files starting with an uppercase letter?

Comment: I was able to pull a clone, do a merge and get it all up, but integrity still has a issue with one of the files, it might be because of the uppercase.

Comment: you shouldn't use a repo with integrity errors.

Comment: True, however I am not sure what the problem with the image is exactly

Comment: @matthewb the problem is that somehow you or something deleted the in-repo history of those files. So you need to remove it from the history, or try to repair it (for example by posting the file I talked about earlier online). If you want realtime help, #mercurial on freenode might be better.

Comment: @matthewb just ping me on IRC, on #mercurial when you can.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try running `hg verify` on your repository and see if that helps.

Comment: It will not directly help, it can only help find us what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

I am having the same problem but in my case `hg verify` returns no errors. Maybe this will help you:

> You could try recloning and reindexing. This will fetch a fresh clone
>   from the remote repository and reindex the repository

Source:

https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/59049/fisheye-cannot-pull-from-mercurial

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem with Mercurial reporting an unknown parent but instead was subsequently throwing a `ValueError` in `dirstate`

Running `hg verify` appeared to complete successfully but did not fix the issue.

Reading the contents of the `dirstate` file, it contained strings referencing a different and unrelated project so to me it was corrupt, the resolution was to copy the backup `dirstate` file over the top of the corrupt `dirstate`, i.e.,
(Windows flavour command)

```
ren .hg\dirstate .hg\dirstate.corrupt
copy .hg\undo.backup.dirstate .hg\dirstate
```

This got Mercurial running again and allowed a simple repair to the previous changes.

The corrupt dirstate seems likely to have been caused by syncing software (OneDrive you know who you are)